# How to get a augment output associated to snk.test output by grouped data in the same table

Tags: r

I already asked for help regarding this case and with the help of many participants here, I was able to find a solution, and now I have an additional question, that I hope someone can help me with

Here is a short description of my case :

I'm running an "lm" regression to a large dataset by location. My datasets consists on 4 columns :

Y = response variable

X1 : 1st explanatory variable

X2 : 2nd explanatory variable

Location : is the column to group my data, so "lm" runs by Location. Here is the code I'm using to get Predicted and Studentized-residuals by observation:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(broom)
    library(dplyr)

    dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
    dataset$perf <- as.numeric(dataset$perf)
    dataset$factor1 <- as.factor(dataset$factor1)
    dataset$factor2 <- as.factor(dataset$factor2)

    dataset <- dataset %>% 
                 group_by(location) %>% 
                 mutate(row=row_number())

    df <- dataset %>%
      group_by(location) %>% 
      mutate(unique_factor1 = n_distinct(factor1), 
             unique_factor1 = n_distinct(factor1), 
             var = var(perf)) %>% 
    filter( unique_factor1 != 1 & unique_factor2 != 1 & var != 0 ) %>%
    do(cbind(row = .$row, lm(perf ~ factor1 + factor2, data = .) %>% augment)) %>%
    right_join(. , dataset, by=c("location", "row"))
```

The object "df" gives me exactly what I need, i.e : my original dataset + the output of "augment".

My need now, is to extend this table to the SNK.test output, specifically the "group" column summarizing letters of the SNK test related to the means comparison of Factor1.

Can anyone help me on how to integrate this command in my code?

Here below a sample of my dataset :

```
location      perf   Factor1  Factor2
1             32         1     1
1             44         1     2
1             58         1     3
1             76         2     1
1             73         2     2
1             37         2     3
1             52         3     1
1             78         3     2
1             60         3     3
2             93         1     1
2             78         1     2
2             25         1     3
2             97         2     1
2             85         2     2
2             60         2     3
2             70         3     1
2             62         3     2
2             95         3     3
```

Thanks a lot !